# Is there a specific distribution formed by the convolution of $k$ Pareto distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

We know that Erlang distribution is the convolution of Exponential distributions, i.e., if $X\sim \mathrm{Exponential}(\lambda)$, then

$$
\sum_i^k X_i\sim\mathrm{Erlang}(k, \lambda).
$$

Is there such a distribution that I can use to describe a similar behaviour? [Convolution of two Pareto distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115291/what-distribution-results-in-adding-two-pareto-distributions) is apparently given by hypergeometric functions, but there is no further information on the existence of such a distribution.

My research arrived at two different distributions, [multivariate Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_Pareto_distribution) and [generalised Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution). From initial inspection of the PDF of bivariate Pareto distribution, I feel like what I am looking for might be multivariate Pareto distribution, I cannot be sure by myself.

Thanks in advance!